# Using Marshal.InitHandle correctly

Tags: c#, interop, clr, marshalling

The `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class has a method called `InitHandle`. It is documented as initializing the underlying handle of a `SafeHandle` object.

But what is the point? Can't you just use the constructor of the `SafeHandle` subclass to do this just as easily?

Comment: It is [very boring](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/12a8819eee9865eb38bca6c05fdece1053102854/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L1326).  The proposal to add it [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46830) , they didn't like SafeHandle.SetHandle().

Comment: The gist of it is that they wanted any non-abstract class derived from `SafeHandle` to be easily producible with code generators (a la public parameterless ctor), so they then needed a way to init the handle value. As @HansPassant says, it's all pretty boring.